# Why does my compiler not supporting "auto" keyword in c++?

Tags: c++, auto

for this code:

```
for(auto x=v.begin(); x!=v.end(); x++)
        cout<<*x<<"  ";
```

I get the following error:

```
error: 'x' does not name a type
  for(auto x=v.begin(); x!=v.end(); x++)
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Which plattfom? `auto` was introduced with C++11

Comment: `auto` in this guise is C++11 onwards.

Comment: @da-chiller - Not true.   The `auto` keyword has been in every C++ version.   It was repurposed in C++11.